# When & Where do you clear State in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this code

```
import React from 'react';

import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import 'materialize-css/js/materialize.js';
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
import '../styles/main.scss';

export default class AddStorageModal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { storageName: "", sharingKey: "" };
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }
    validate() {
        if (this.state.storageName === "" && this.state.sharingKey == "") {
            console.log("validation error");
            return false;
        }
        this.props.createNewStorage(this.state);
    }
    resetForm() {
        this.setState({ storageName: "", sharingKey: "" })
        $(function () {
            Materialize.updateTextFields();
        });
    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.storages.openAddStorageModal) {
            $('#add-new-storage-modal').openModal({ dismissible: false });
        }
        else {
            $('#add-new-storage-modal').closeModal();
            this.resetForm( );
        }
        return (
            <div id="add-new-storage-modal" className="modal" >
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <h6>Enter your new Storage (Freezer, Pantry, etc.) </h6>
                    <div className="row">
                        <form>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="storage_name" type="text" value={this.state.storageName} name="storageName" onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) } />
                                <label htmlFor="storage_name">Storage Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <h4 className="center">OR</h4>
                            <h6>Enter in the sharing key you were given.</h6>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="sharing_key" type="text"  value={this.state.sharingKey} name="sharingKey" onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) }  />
                                <label htmlFor="sharing_key">Sharking Key</label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#!" className="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left" onClick={() => this.validate() }>Add</a>
                    <a href="#!" className="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" onClick={() => this.props.loadAddStorageModal(false) }>Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My orignal plan was each time my modal dialog re-renders I reset the form values by calling my resetForm() method.

This does not work as I get errors about "changing state" in the render what does now make sense to me as it will cause the component to re-render.

But this leads to me to the questions where do I clear the state then? I am trying to follow the redux pattern.

I could do the clearing in "Validate()" method when the add is clicked.

However "createNewStorage" does an ajax call. I am unsure how I would handle the situation if the ajax call fails. As a user I would expect a error message to be displayed but the modal should still be open with my inputted values.

Here is full code if needed.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import NavigationContainer from './NavigationContainer';
import StorageItemsContainer from './StorageItemsContainer'

import AddStorageModal from './AddStorageModal.js'
import {loadAddStorageModal, createNewStorage} from '../actions/StorageActions.js'
import '../styles/main.scss';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationContainer />
         <div className="container">
          <StorageItemsContainer />
         </div>
        <AddStorageModal {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        storages: state.storages
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({loadAddStorageModal: loadAddStorageModal, createNewStorage: createNewStorage}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Action

```
export function fetchStorage() {
  return function(dispatch) {
      var payload = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Fridge2",
            selected: true
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Closet2",
            selected: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Car2",
            selected: false
        }
    ];
     dispatch({type: "Fetch_Storage", payload: payload});
  }
}

export function loadAddStorageModal(load) {
    return function(dispatch) {
         dispatch({type: "Load_Add_Storage_Modal", payload: load});
    }
}

export function createNewStorage(storage) {
    return function(dispatch) {
         dispatch({type: "New_Storage_Created", payload: storage});
    }
}

export function selectStorage(storageId)
{
    return function(dispatch) {
         dispatch({type: "Select_Storage", payload: storageId});
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    fetchedStorages: [],
    openAddStorageModal: false,
    selectedStorage: null
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "Fetch_Storage": {
            var selected;
            if(state.fetchedStorages != [])
            {
                selected =  action.payload[0]
            }
            return {
                fetchedStorages: action.payload,
                selectedStorage: selected
            }
        }
        case "Load_Add_Storage_Modal": {
            return {  
                openAddStorageModal: action.payload,
                fetchedStorages: state.fetchedStorages,
                selectedStorage: state.selectedStorage
            }
        }
        case "New_Storage_Created": {
            var lastStorage = state.fetchedStorages.slice(-1);  // just for now
            return {
                openAddStorageModal: false,
                fetchedStorages: state.fetchedStorages.concat({ id: lastStorage[0].id + 1,  name:  action.payload.storageName}),
                selectedStorage: state.selectedStorage
            }
        }
        case "Select_Storage": {
            var existingStorages =  state.fetchedStorages;
            var selectedStorage = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < existingStorages.length; i++) {
                 var storage = existingStorages[i];
                 if (action.payload == storage.id) {
                     storage.selected = true;
                     selectedStorage = storage;
                 }else{
                     storage.selected = false;
                 }
                 existingStorages[i] = storage;
            }
            return {
                fetchedStorages: existingStorages,
                selectedStorage: selectedStorage
            }

        }
    }


    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only call `setState` in lifecycle methods and in `onEvents`.

In your case, because you are relying on props `this.props.storages.openAddStorageModal`

you could set your state inside `componentWillReceiveProps` **lifecycle-method**.

it will be called with the `nextProps` values, note that props are not set at this time, and you can compare the `nextProps` argument with your previous props in `this.props`

add this to your component, and it should work fine:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.storages.openAddStorageModal) {
      $('#add-new-storage-modal').openModal({ dismissible: false });
  } else {
      $('#add-new-storage-modal').closeModal();
      this.resetForm(); // will work fine here..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an action which clears the state - `dispatch(props.clearForm)`.

Your store on receiving the action event should be responsible for clearing it's store state and thus a re-render will be triggered.

```
case CLEAR_FORM:
    // return new empty state object
```

Your form should be displaying values based on the state of the store and so when the re-render happens the fields should be empty.

If you're writing new values to the store on every keystroke you may want to debounce the action event or else you might have perf issues.

Comment: I am using Redux so I only have 1 store. I did not think that it would be right to my 2 states living outside that component as they are only used there. Once the user has hit "add" then it gets added to my store but till then I was thinking it would be better to be local as nothing else should be trying to use values that are not even finalized yet.